# Library for Part of Speech tagging and Sentiment Analysis in Android?

Tags: android, stanford-nlp, ibm-watson, alchemyapi, watson-conversation

I want to add an `AI Agent` specially `Part of Speech tagging` in `Android` application. Can I do it using `AlchemyApi`? Or any other Library that works in Android? I tried `StanfordCoreNLP` but I am unable to use it in `Android`. This [link](http://www.alchemyapi.com/tools/android) is not working for downloading `Alchemy AndoidSDK Api`. I read a lot of links  even Can I use it in Android or not? Kindly guide.

Answer (score 2):

```
 compile 'com.ibm.watson.developer_cloud:java-sdk:3.3.0'
```

Add that to your Gradle
And look here for [examples](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/java-sdk)

```
 AlchemyLanguage service = new AlchemyLanguage();
    service.setApiKey("<api_key>");

    Map<String,Object> params;
    params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    params.put(AlchemyLanguage.TEXT, "IBM Watson won the Jeopardy television show hosted by Alex Trebek");
    CombinedResults combinedResults=service.getCombinedResults(params).execute();
    List<SAORelation> relationObject=combinedResults.getRelations();
    for (SAORelation relation: relationObject){
        System.out.println(relation.getSentence());
    }
```

Look [here](https://alchemy-language-demo.mybluemix.net/) for a demo of what the Alchemy Api can do

Comment: `api key`? Is it from `AlchemyApi key` or `IBM-Alchemy Api` ke?

Comment: On compiling your code, After taking `api key`. it is giving the error `I/CredentialUtils: JNDI string lookups is not available.`

Comment: That's not an error This method private static String getKeyUsingJNDI(String serviceName) should always return null on Android due to the javax functions being unsupported  it's just a warning